# the full navigation bar is not visible on mobile devices also the text in the middle of the page is too large

Tags: html, css, alignment, scaling

I'm started learing html/css my first project was portfolio and i fell in this issue.
the full navigation bar is not visible on mobile devices also the text in the middle of the page is too large.

site source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>OPGL Portfolio</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="nav">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/74413191?s=400&u=7076f19ee2d11687d44fe772ee5a76ce3c437679&v=4" alt="logo" height="50px" width="50px">
                    <h1>OPGL</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-links">
                    <a href="./index.html">Home</a>
                    <a href="index.html">About</a>
                    <a href="https://github.com/OPGL">Projects</a>
                    <a href="./utils/mail.html">Contact</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <h1>Hi,<br/>
                    I'm Dawid,<br/>
                    <div>Begginer Developer</div>
                </h1>
                <p>&#60;!-- Begginer Web Developer, see more in about section --&#62;</p>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <p>Made by Dawid Ploch via VSCode</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abel&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:ital@1&display=swap');
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    background: #080a0b;
}
.container {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.logo {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.nav-links {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.nav-links a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.nav-links a:hover {
    color: #00b894;
}
.content {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.content h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    padding: 20px;
}
.content h1 div {
    font-size: 30px;
}
.content p {
    text-align: center;
    color: gray;
}
.footer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #0d1012;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    min-width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -150px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.footer p {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

hosted website: [link](https://opgl.github.io/Portfolio/)

i expect that Navigation Bar and text should smaller on mobile devices.
everything should be 100% visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the nav links stack by changing `display: flex;` to `display: inline-block;` in CSS under `.nav-links`

And if you want the text in the middle to be smaller you can simply change the font size in this part of your CSS:

```
.content h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    padding: 20px;
}
.content h1 div {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Now to put it all together so this only happens on mobiles and small screens, you can simply just add this code to your CSS under a media query like this:

```
@media (max-width: 750px) {
  .nav-links {
    display: inline-block;
    align-items: center;
}
  
  .content h1 {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    padding: 20px;
}
.content h1 div {
    font-size: 12px;
}
  
}
```

Here it is working:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abel&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:ital@1&display=swap');
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    background: #080a0b;
}
.container {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.logo {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.nav-links {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.nav-links a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.nav-links a:hover {
    color: #00b894;
}
.content {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.content h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    padding: 20px;
}
.content h1 div {
    font-size: 30px;
}
.content p {
    text-align: center;
    color: gray;
}
.footer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #0d1012;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    min-width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -150px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.footer p {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}


@media (max-width: 750px) {
  .nav-links {
    display: inline-block;
    align-items: center;
}
  
  .content h1 {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    padding: 20px;
}
.content h1 div {
    font-size: 12px;
}
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>OPGL Portfolio</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="nav">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/74413191?s=400&u=7076f19ee2d11687d44fe772ee5a76ce3c437679&v=4" alt="logo" height="50px" width="50px">
                    <h1>OPGL</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-links">
                    <a href="./index.html">Home</a>
                    <a href="index.html">About</a>
                    <a href="https://github.com/OPGL">Projects</a>
                    <a href="./utils/mail.html">Contact</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <h1>Hi,<br/>
                    I'm Dawid,<br/>
                    <div>Begginer Developer</div>
                </h1>
                <p>&#60;!-- Begginer Web Developer, see more in about section --&#62;</p>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <p>Made by Dawid Ploch via VSCode</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```